# What is the index tuple maximum size in postgres?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-11

I'm quoting https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/sql-createindex.html in regards to the `INCLUDE` clause:

> It's wise to be conservative about adding non-key columns to an index, especially wide columns. If an index tuple exceeds the maximum size allowed for the index type, data insertion will fail. In any case, non-key columns duplicate data from the index's table and bloat the size of the index, thus potentially slowing searches.

I'm wondering what is this `index tuple max size` for btree indexes which might fail inserts.

Use case: I am considering `INCLUDE`ing a json column (<1000 chars) to a unique index.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is a function of the block size, slightly less than 1/3 of it for btree indexes.  For the default 8kB block size, the maximum is 2704 bytes:

```
insert into foo select string_agg(x::text,'') from generate_series(1,940) f(x);
ERROR:  index row size 2728 exceeds btree version 4 maximum 2704 for index "foo_pkey"
```